# Phase Shift between two noisy signals of Stochastic Resonance

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

for task 3 I wanna try to calculate phase shift between my noisy signal and Periodic forcing, I used Cross correlation method but phase shift becomes very small and does not make sense, I filtered my noisy signal or different methods but did not work , do you have any Idea how I should calculate exactly phase shift ?[image: Image of Task]

At first I plotted Noisy signal and than Calculated  phase shift between noisy signal(x) and periodic forcing (x2)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as signal
simulation_time = 100.0
sigma = 0.3
A =10
T=100
omega = 0.1
dt = 0.001
sqdt = np.sqrt(dt) #Precompute
time = np.arange(0, simulation_time, dt)
x = np.empty(len(time))
x2 = np.empty(len(time))
#Initial conditions 
x[0] = 1.0

i = 1
for t in time[1:]:
    fx = x[i-1] - x[i-1]*x[i-1]*x[i-1] + A*np.cos(omega*t)
    x2[i]=A*np.cos(omega*t)
    gx = sigma
    x[i] = x[i-1] + dt*fx + sqdt*gx*np.random.standard_normal()
    i += 1
plt.figure()
plt.plot(time, x)
plt.plot(time, x2)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('signal')
plt.show()

#cross corelation method 
output = np.correlate(x,x2*0.15,mode='same')
lags   = time-50
plt.plot(lags,output)
maximum = np.max(output)
phase_shift = lags[output==maximum][0]
phase_shift


0.05799999999999983
```

Comment: Not sure this is the best website for this question. It does not really looks like a pure programming/algorithmic question. I think you can get more attention on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, verify against an FFT. This is not as efficient, but is more intuitive to interpret:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


simulation_time = 100.0
sigma = 0.3
A = 10
T = 100
omega = 0.1
dt = 0.001
sqdt = np.sqrt(dt)  # Precompute
time = np.arange(0, simulation_time, dt)
x = np.empty(len(time))
x2 = np.empty(len(time))

# Initial conditions
x[0] = 1.0

i = 1
for t in time[1:]:
    fx = x[i-1] - x[i-1]*x[i-1]*x[i-1] + A*np.cos(omega*t)
    x2[i] = A*np.cos(omega*t)
    gx = sigma
    x[i] = x[i-1] + dt*fx + sqdt*gx*np.random.standard_normal()
    i += 1


spectrum = np.fft.rfft(x)
freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(x), d=dt)
i_peak = np.argmax(spectrum)
phase = np.angle(spectrum[i_peak])
shift = phase+np.pi/2

print(f'Peak frequency: {freqs[i_peak]} Hz - should be close to {omega/2/np.pi:.6}')
print(f'Peak phase: {phase:.6} rad')
print(f'Phase shift from cosine: {shift:.3} rad, or {shift/2/np.pi:.1%}')

plt.figure()
plt.plot(time, x)
plt.plot(time, x2)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('signal')
plt.show()
```

```
Peak frequency: 0.02 Hz - should be close to 0.0159155
Peak phase: -1.4046 rad
Phase shift from cosine: 0.166 rad, or 2.6%
```